Critical error for priceset w/ fields visible to admin? version 5.77.1
Has anyone experienced issues with PriceSet after upgrading to version 5.77.1?
I rely on PriceSet for our events.  What I notice is that, if a priceset contains an entire field that is set to admin only, then the registration page will throw a critical error.  The registration page works again once I disable those admin-only fields.  Curious if anyone else experience this?

can be super helpful when asking these types of questions if you can see whether the problem can be replicated on one of the 'master' (latest code) sites eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ that way any recent fixes for regressions will already be in play (in theory) and it helps rule out other factors

If you can add more details about critical error , easy to suggest any solution.
